# If condition in Github Actions for another Job

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

My use case is, to trigger docs build when there is a trigger word in Pull Request Comments.
I am using [pull-request-comment-trigger](https://github.com/Khan/pull-request-comment-trigger) to know if a **Trigger word** is present in the code.

After knowing Action is triggered, I want to run some commands inside the repo. So, I have to use [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) for that.

My doubt is, inside the `run` command, Only Shell Commands are valid, Right? I want to run another job **if** above condition satisfies.

My Current Yaml File

```yaml
name: Testing GH Actions

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: khan/pull-request-comment-trigger@master
        id: check
        with:
          trigger: "AppajiC"
          reaction: rocket
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
      - run:
        # Generally Anything here runs if below condition satisfies.
        # I want to run another job here, which uses actions/checkout@v2 action
        if: steps.check.outputs.triggered == 'true'
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can use the same if condition in your checkout step. Alternatively, you can create a new job that has that if condition for the entire job, so you don't need to repeat the if for every step.

Comment: Could you please give a example snippet?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the condition for your **checkout** step and the following steps:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  if: steps.check.outputs.triggered == 'true'

- name: Following step1
  if: steps.check.outputs.triggered == 'true'

...
```

Alternatively, you can create a  new job and use that if condition once:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      deploy-status: ${{ steps.check.outputs.triggered }}
    steps:
      - uses: khan/pull-request-comment-trigger@master
        id: check
        with:
          trigger: 'AppajiC'
          reaction: rocket
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}

  # this job will only run if steps.check.outputs.triggered == 'true'
  # you just need to write the if once
  after-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [deploy]
    if: needs.deploy.outputs.deploy-status == 'true'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      ...
```